# MVC: Ошибка при вызове представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Ошибка возникает при нажатии на ссылку "Добавить клиента", запускает действие, которое отображает соотв. представление (см. ниже)

**Ошибка:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Имена типов проверки в ненавязчивых правилах проверки должны быть уникальными. Следующие типы проверки встречаются более одного раза: required"

**Класс:**

```
public class Client
{
    [Required, Range(1, 999999, ErrorMessage = "ID клиентв указан неверно")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Длинна ФИО не боеле 100 символов")]
    public string Fio { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2018", "12/12/3000")]
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }

}
```

**Представление: (Добавление)**
(Местоположение ошибки указал в конце соответствующей строки)

```
@model mvc_CLientBase2.Models.Client

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddClient3</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Client</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })  <!- ТУТ ОШИБКА !!!!!!!-->
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Нагуглить я ничего не смог, поэтому прошу Вашей помощи. 
Спасибо

Comment: А потому что вы ставите русскую студию и гуглите русский текст ошибки. А на английском инфы намного больше. Например: [Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9746186/5752652)

Answer (score 3):

В моем случае подошел вариант из статьи ([вот она](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746186/validation-type-names-in-unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique)), предоставленный A K .

Я закомментировал в конфиге в апп.сеттингс 2 записи:

> add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"
>   add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"

Заработало.